# IIS URL Rewrite breaking Postbackurl to other domain on form button

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

We have a site which consists of 4 pages in this order of flow:
Default.aspx
List.aspx
SubmitForm.aspx
Thankyou.aspx

We use IIS URL Rewrite module to use a PURL for the landing (default) page. So this:
www.example.com/Chris123
is really this:
www.example.com/default.aspx?UID=Chris123

On the SubmitForm.aspx we have the submit button with a PostBackURL value which sends the form data to SalesForce.com's servers, captures the data, then redirects back to our Thankyou.aspx page.

Is the past, we haven't used the URL Rewrite module and the SalesForce submission has worked just fine. Now, however, with the URL Rewrite rules enabled, when the user clicks the button instead of going to the SalesForce server it redirects back to the form page, clears out the fields and fires all the form validation. This basically just causes a loop of form submit/redirect/form submit/redirect...

If I go into IIS and disable the User-Friendly URL rule (used only for the Default.aspx page) the form submits as expected to SalesForce. Turn it back on and the form submits to itself again.

I don't have a ton of experience with the URL Rewrite -- just basic User Friendly type scenarios. Any suggestions on where to poke around first would be appreciated.

We are running Windows Web Server 2008, app is .NET 4 web forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out.

The issue ended up being that the WebResource.axd was getting caught by the URL Rewrite. Fixed it by adding this to the rule:

```
<!-- The following condition prevents rule from rewriting requests to .axd files -->
<add input="{URL}" negate="true" pattern="\.axd$" />
```

I'd read about that earlier but didn't think it was my issue since the PostBackURL was going off to another server. But I guess it makes sense since the PostBackURL needs the Javascript to redirect the post. rOnly reason I caught it was because my log file was capturing "WebResource.axd" as my PURL value with the form as the Referrer.

Here is the page where I found the actual code (at the end) which fixed my issue:
http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewriting-for-aspnet-web-forms